# How to split training dataset and testing data set

Tags: python, machine-learning

I need to split dataset into training a testing without using sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.

I want the approach to be as follows:

1. Read dataset from excel with 100 rows (DONE):

   ```
   data = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
   ```
2. From the 100 rows, select 75% **random** rows as testing data (DONE):

   ```
   random_training = dataset.sample(75)
   ```
3. Use a for loop to check which indexes exist in data list, but do not exist in random_training list. If not existing in random_training list, then put in list random_testing list. This is where I am finding it hard to execute. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you want to use train_test_split? You can transform your excel file into pandas dataframe, then easily work with that.

Comment: Probably homework assignment rules.. @hyper-cookie

Comment: Whey not just randomized your frame first, then take 75 of it as training and the rest or 25% is for testing?

Comment: I will use `data.sample(frac=1)` to first randomize the dataset and then select the first 75 rows for training and the last 25 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataLoader` and `SubsetRandomSampler` and `random.sample`:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,SubsetRandomSampler
import random

indices = random.sample(range(1, len(dataset)), (int)(len(dataset)*0.75))
missing_indices = [index 
                    for index in range(0, len(dataset))
                    if index not in indices]
dl_valid = DataLoader(dataset,batch_size,sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(indices.astype("int")),num_workers = num_workers)
dl_train = DataLoader(dataset,batch_size,sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(missing_indices.astype("int")),num_workers = num_workers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tr=list(random_training.index)
testing=data.loc[data.index.drop(tr)]
```